# how to call a connection in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.net c#

I have a program that the connection is declare in every method.

How can i call the connection so that i will declare the connection once and can be called by other method? is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, I do something like this

```
public static DataContext getConnection()
    {
        String SqlOptions = "Put your connection string here";

        return new SqlConnection(SqlOptions);

    }
```

if you want you can also make it a property, or call the connection string from the config file like showed in another post

Comment: What about writing up you connection string in configuration file?

Comment: then from this? i can now call that in any method i want ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about resuing SQLConnection object, then its better, the way you have it now. When it comes to database connection its better if you create is as late as possible and close as early as possible.

Best is to use `using` block while declaring a connection.

```
using(SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    // your work. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you app or web.config add

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="server=server;database=database;uid=username;pwd=password;Connect Timeout=900" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

then add the using System.Configuration; as reference and call it

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Code Project Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12300/An-ASP-NET-Application-Using-a-MySQL-Database)

This will give you all idea about database connectivity in asp.net with c#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your scenario, but I'll try to give you an idea. You can create a connection class with 2 methods: `ExecuteSqlScript()` and `ExecuteStoredProcedure()`, and instantiate it at the beginning of the page where you need it. You call the method and you can fill the `DataSet`.